# Prove that for each $\phi \in S_n$, $\det A=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{j=1}^n a_{\phi(j)\sigma(j)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, determinant, symmetric-groups

> Assume that  a permutation $\phi \in S_n$ is given.
>   Prove that :
>   $$\det A=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn} (\sigma)\space   
> a_{\phi(1)\sigma(1)}a_{\phi(2)\sigma(2)} \cdots a_{\phi(n)\sigma(n)}$$

My Try :
The point is to choose an element from each row. So we have (am I correct?) :
$$\forall \phi \in S_n\space \quad
\det A=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\space   
a_{\phi(1)\sigma(\phi(1))}a_{\phi(2)\sigma(\phi(2))}\dots a_{\phi(n)\sigma(\phi(n))}$$

So, It holds for $\sigma \phi^{-1}$ as $\phi$.

Thus we have :
$$\det A=\sum_{\sigma\phi^{-1} \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma\phi^{-1})\space   
a_{\phi(1)\sigma\phi^{-1}(\phi(1))}a_{\phi(2)\sigma\phi^{-1}(\phi(2))}\dots a_{\phi(n)\sigma\phi^{-1}(\phi(n))}$$

$$=\sum_{\sigma\phi^{-1} \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\operatorname{sgn}\left(\phi^{-1}\right )\space   a_{\phi(1)\sigma(1)}a_{\phi(2)\sigma(2)}\dots a_{\phi(n)\sigma(n)}$$

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I think there is a missing $\operatorname{sgn} \phi$?

Comment: @copper.hat no it's not :) i'm sure cause my teacher used this one in another page of my notebook... take a look at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Permutation_of_Determinant_Indices ... i can't understand the proof myself ...

Comment: Read the link again, you are missing the sign of a permutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\{ (\phi(k), \sigma(k)) \}_k = \{ (k, \sigma(\phi^{-1}(k))) \}_k = \{ (k, (\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})(k)) \}_k$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma)\space   
a_{\phi(1)\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n)\sigma(n)} 
&=& \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma)\space   
a_{1 (\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})(1)}\cdots a_{n (\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})(n)} \\
&=& \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma\circ \phi^{-1}) \operatorname{sgn} (\phi) \space   
a_{1 (\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})(1)}\cdots a_{n (\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})(n)} \\
&=& \operatorname{sgn} (\phi) 
\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})  \space   
a_{1 (\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})(1)}\cdots a_{n (\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})(n)} \\
&=& \operatorname{sgn} (\phi) \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma)\space   
a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}\\
&=& \operatorname{sgn} (\phi) \det A
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Would you please explain what you wrote at the first line ?

Comment: It is an equality of the collection of indices of $A$.

Comment: Why those sets have indices?

Comment: A typical line looks like $a_{\phi(1)\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{\phi(n)\sigma(n)} $ so the indices for this line are $(\phi(1),\sigma(1)),\cdots, (\phi(n),\sigma(n))$. All I meant was that these can be rearranged into $(1,(\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})(1)),\cdots,(n,(\sigma\circ \phi^{-1})(n))$.